# Visual C# error when changing anchor for multiple controls

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, properties, file-not-found

Visual C# 2008 is giving an error when I attempt to change the anchor for multiple controls simultaneously. This error does not occur when done individually.

> Property value is not valid.
>
> Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\test\test\Resources\WelcomeBorder.png'.

The image was previously used as a background image for a panel (not one of the elements selected, though they're in it), but all references to the image have been deleted. A search through the entire solution for the string "WelcomeBorder" returned no finds. The solution has been repeatedly rebuilt since.

The file has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error when I manually deleted an image from the Resources directory.  I had to put back the images back in the directory that it was complaining about and then right click Reesources.resx to delete them the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file reference still exists in Resources.resx